# MySQL and Bizzare Backslash escape problem

Tags: mysql, backslash

This failed in Java 13 (JDBC) code so I went to MySQL Workbench to duplicate problem.

I run a simple query as:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SET SESSION sql_mode = NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES;

SELECT *, "x\\x", "y\y" from dirs 
WHERE d_pathname like 'E:\\\\BOOKS\\\\Dictionaries_and_Encyclopedias\\\\%' ORDER BY d_pathname;
```

and I get 400 rows returned.  The issue is, that I do not want to use double-backslashes.

Rows returned show a single backslash, not a double backslash.

Interestingly, the `x\\x` and `y\y` clauses appear just as represented in the SELECT statement.

When I remove the double backslashes in the `LIKE` clause, I get zero rows!

Why?  I'd rather not have to double-up the backslashes, and run simple and clean code.

Answer (score 0):

The `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES` mode only affects how backslashes are treated in ordinary string literals. It doesn't change how they're processed in `LIKE` patterns.

However, you can use the `ESCAPE` option to specify a different character to use as the escape character in `LIKE`. Just use some other character that doesn't appear in your pattern.

```
WHERE d_pathname like 'E:\BOOKS\Dictionaries_and_Encyclopedias\%' ESCAPE '|'
```